# ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref' ошибка при установке python3.6

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x

Версия ОС - Ubuntu 16.04. Собственно начал установку python3.6 через `apt-get`. В процессе установки получит ошибку:

```
Настраивается пакет python3.6-minimal (3.6.0-2~16.04.york0) …

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import importlib._bootstrap_external
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/functools.py", line 23, in <module>
    from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python3.6-minimal (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 python3.6-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Хотя сам `python` работает:

```
constantine@ssd:~$ python3.6
Python 3.6.0 (default, Mar 10 2017, 23:45:28) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Но ошибка не дает покоя. Может кто ни будь сталкивался?

Comment: Проблема с sys.path в питоне. Похожая история тут https://github.com/peacegiverman/cx_Freeze-deb-wheels

Comment: Если есть, то удалите ручную установку питона из /usr/local. См. [python3.5-minimal wont configure](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=852163)

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил вот так `sudo apt-get autoremove`, не знаю как это связано..